# Passing parameter from different source into insert statement using Nifi

Tags: oracle, apache-nifi

I'm still new in NiFi. What I want to achieve is to pass a parameter from a different source.

Scenario:

I have 2 datasource which is Json data and record id (from oracle function). I declared record id using extract text as "${recid}" and json string default is "$1" .

How to insert into table using sql statement  insert into table1 (json,recid) value ('$1','${recid}')

After I run the processor. I'm not able to get both attribute into one insert statement.

Please help.

[Nifi flowfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX4NY.png)
[Flowfile after mergecontent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njh8X.png)

Answer (score 0):

you should merge these 2 flowfiles to make one.
Use mergeFlowfile processor with Attribute Strategy set to Keep All Unique Attributes

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html

Comment: Hi Maxime. Thanks for reply. I have tried using merge content. both attribute json and recid (value) goes into 1 flow file. My question is how to declare json and recid as a different attribute and put into insert statement as. Kindly refer new screenshot I attached.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at LookupAttribute with a SimpleDatabaseLookupService. You can pass your JSON flow file into that, look up the `recid` into an attribute, then do the ExtractText -> ReplaceText to get it into SQL form.